# Using RabbitMQ with an Ionic app

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework, rabbitmq

I've been exploring Ionic framework and I want to make an app that, via JavaScript, connects to a server that has a PHP script running and sending messages to a RabbitMQ queue, but I don't know how I can do the first part... I've followed some tutorials on RabbitMQ and already made a JS script that receives my messages sent by the PHP script, but I cannot figure out how to use that script in the Ionic app. I can, however, run both scripts in the terminal and make it work, but I'm completely lost when trying to perform a receiver in the Ionic app.

Has anyone done anything similar to this? If so, can you please tell me a plugin to make the connection between Ionic and RabbitMQ?

Thank you very much!

---

**P.S.** I know this doesn't help but this is the script that I've retrieved from RabbitMQ official tutorials (and that receives my messages):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: true});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the best way to do this is by using **Web Stomp** and **SockJS**!